# Finding percentage in Python

Tags: python, floating-point, percentage

A question for python beginners:

Anybody knows 20/200*100 is 10. But python says 0!

Check this code:

```
print 20/200*100
```

Do you know why this happens and how to solve this problem?

Comment: This happens in Python 2 but not 3, as a result of integer division. You can put `from __future__ import division` at the beginning of your files to get the expected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

In Python2, `/` is a truncated division if both arguments are int

You can just use a `float` literal instead of converting an int to a float

```
>>> 20/200.0*100
10.0
```

or multiply by 100.0 first if the other two variables are int

```
>>> 100.0*20/200
10.0
```

Comment: Nice answer. But it won't support variables.

Comment: @Nandakumar, you may use `100.0*20/200` if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Why this happens:

```
20/200 is 0.01

0.01 -> int = 0

0*100 = 0
```

How to solve:

Use:

```
print float(20)/200*100
```

or:

```
print 20.0*100/200
```

But note that it won't support variables.

Comment: `20*100/200` is not a good solution - imagine what would happen if OP wants to compute `21/200` as a percentage. Also, you only need to floatify one of the values in the division for a floating point division. Thus, `float(20)/200 * 100` would be sufficient

Comment: If you're using constants, use: 20.0*100.0/200.0.

Answer (score 0):

```
print (20/float(200)*100)
```

use `float(x)` to the numerator or the denominator if the answer is going to be decimal number